# Creating and doing Market basket analysis from raw data

Tags: data-mining, correlation, market-basket-analysis, pearson-correlation

I have a data set with me which have many items and their sales data in terms of amount and quantity sold rolled up per week. I want to figure out that is there some correlation between the two or not, trying to access that if sales of one item affecting the other's sale or not, in terms of any positive or negative effect.
Consider the following type of data:

```
Week #   Product #        Sale($)       Quantity  
Week 1   Product 1         1              1
         Product 2         2              1  
         Product 3         3              1
Week 2   Product 1         3              2
         Product 3         2              1
         Product 6         2              2
Week 3   Product 4         2              1
         Product 3         1              2
         Product 5         4              2
```

So,from the above data on week basis, I want to figure out that how can I convert this data into a form of market basket data with the above set of parameters available with me. Since, there isn't any market basket data available.

```
The parameters I could think of is :
To use the count or occurrences of each product in a given week.
To use the total quantity sold 
To use the total sales to find correlation.
```

So, basically I have to come up with how can an item be correlated to the other of the affinity of one product with the other product.No matter it is positively correlated or negative correlated. The only issue is I do not have any primary key to bind the items with a basket or an order number since it's rolled up sales.
Any answers or help in this topic is highly appreciable. In case you find it incomplete, you can let me know for any further clarity.

Comment: Can you provide some data in some format, e.g txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because you have no information about the co-occurrence. You also have data muddled from daily grain to weekly grain. Aggregates won't permit this.